# Category People in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories, alphabetical

I have a question. I would like to get an url like this : `http://www.xyz.com/people/steffi`
Does anyone have an idea ?
And finally, I would like to range people's name like this : A B ..... Z

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can adjust that in the permalinks settings.

try `%category%/%post_name%`

look here for more in depth info. http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: Nope... Not like this... Do you have another solution, please ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's a custom content (or post) type.  A good plugin to control custom post types is [CMS Press](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cms-press/).  You could set up a custom post type of people, and then have categories for each letter of the alphabet.  When you put in new posts, just add them to the specific category (letter) that you want.

Comment: Ahhh... Maybe CMS Press =D. Thank you Josh !

Comment: If you liked either answer, vote them up. If one solved your problem, tick it as answered.